# How use a User Defined Type imported from an Addin?

Tags: excel, vba

In **addin.xlam** I have:

```
Type Quantity
    i As Integer
end type

Sub show_quant(q as Quantiy)
    MsgBox(q.i)
end sub
```

In an open workbook, I do:

```
Sub load_addin()
    Dim AI As Excel.AddIn
    Set AI = Application.AddIns.Add(Filename:="add_in.xlam")
    AI.Installed = True

    Dim q As Quantity
    show_quant(q)
End Sub
```

This doesn't work. Excel complains that the User defined type hasn't been defined yet.

So how *do* you declare variables of a type defined in an addin?

Comment: The Add-in Manager in Excel is not available unless there is at least one visible workbook open. Is there a workbook open?

Comment: Yes, `load_addin` gets run in an open workbook. I changed the question to clarify this.